# Android Dyanmic ListView

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, android-listview

So I'm trying to develop a simple android app in eclipse and running it on the virtual device. I have a few photos and audio files in the project's `res` folder. I put the photos in the `drawable-hdpi` folder and the audio files just in the `res` folder. The graphical layout of my activity just has a listview. I want the listview to look inside the `res` folder and find all 4 resources, then populate the list with their names, and the user should be able to click on it and it should open up.

I know how to open, say, the audio file when the user clicks on and play it. I'm just wondering about to make the listview dynamic. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to look inside res folder when you already knew whats inside res folder, If your apk is generated you cannot add new items in res.?

Comment: @Brontok I just don't want to hard code those files. Because let's say in the future I decide to remove those files and replace it with some other ones or I add 10 more files. I can't hard code everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [site](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listview_listviewexample) will probably help with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

you have to specify the resources you want. The listview cannot just go pick up whatever is in the res folder because apps do not have permission to see folders of apps.

What you can do is copy your files to user space and then your listview can pick up the files without naming each